# LocationInterceptionAspect.OnSetValue(LocationInterceptionArgs args): how do I check if the property is an indexer, and get its value?

Tags: c#, postsharp

I use the code below in some aspect to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`:

```
[Serializable]
public class NotifyPropertyChangedAspect : LocationInterceptionAspect {
    /* ... stuff ... */
    public override void OnSetValue(LocationInterceptionArgs args)
    {
        var obj = args.Instance;
        /* ... more stuff ... */
        var oldValue = args.Binding.GetValue(ref obj, Arguments.Empty);
        /* ... extra stuff ... */
    }
}
```

But if my property is an indexer, then it fails with an exception `InvalidCastException`:

`` Unable to cast object of type 'PostSharp.Aspects.Internals.Arguments`1[PostSharp.Aspects.Arguments]' to type 'PostSharp.Aspects.Internals.Arguments`1[System.Int32]'. ``

How do I check if the property is an indexer, and get its value (I'd rather do the checking during compilation, I guess inside the `CompileTimeInitialize` method) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the value of the `LocationInterceptionArgs.Index` property to the `Binding.GetValue` method. The property already contains the correct arguments value.

```
var oldValue = args.Binding.GetValue(ref obj, args.Index)
```

Another option is to call `args.GetCurrentValue()` instead.

-alex